# GROUP_CONCAT with ordering and missing fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of tables that I want to get rows returned from in the following format:

```
Student ID | Last Name | First Name | Quiz Scores
-------------------------------------------------
xxxxxxx    | Snow      | Jon        | 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

There's 3 relevant tables (changing any existing DB structure is not an option):

- `person` - table of all people in the organization
- `enrollment` - table of student and faculty enrollment data
- `tilt.quiz` - table of quiz scores, with each row storing an individual score

The tricky part of this is the Quiz Scores. A row for the quiz score only exists if the student has taken a the quiz. Each `quiz` row has a `module`, 1 - 8. So possible quiz data for a student could be (each of these being a separate row):

```
person_id | module | score
---------------------------
223355    | 1      | 100
223355    | 2      | 95
223355    | 4      | 80
223355    | 7      | 100
```

I need the quiz scores returned in proper order with 8 comma separated values, regardless if any or all of the quizzes are missing.

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT
    person.id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tilt.quiz.score) AS scores
FROM person
    LEFT JOIN enrollment ON person.id = enrollment.person_id
    LEFT JOIN tilt.quiz ON person.id = tilt.quiz.person_id 
WHERE 
    enrollment.course_id = '$num' AND enrollment_status_id = 1
GROUP BY person.id
ORDER BY last_name
```

The problems with this are:

1. It does not order the quizzes by module
2. If any of the quizzes are missing it simply returns fewer values

So I need the `GROUP_CONCAT` scores to at least include commas for missing quiz values, and have them ordered correctly.

The one solution I considered was creating a temporary table of the quiz scores, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient method or exactly how to go about it.

EDIT: Another solution would be to execute a query to check for the existence of each quiz individually but this seems clunky (a total of 9 queries instead of 1); I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: Which table has the module column ?

Comment: The quiz table, edited to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some assumptions here about your data structure, but this should be pretty close to what you're after. Take a look at the documentation for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

```mysql
SELECT `person`.`id`, `person`.`first_name`, `person`.`last_name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    COALESCE(`tilt`.`quiz`.`score`, 'N/A')
    ORDER BY `tilt`.`quiz`.`module_id`
  ) AS `scores`
FROM `person`
CROSS JOIN `modules`
LEFT JOIN `enrollment` USING (`person_id`)
LEFT JOIN `tilt`.`quiz` USING (`person_id`, `module_id`)
WHERE (`enrollment`.`course_id` = '$num')
  AND (`enrollment`.`enrollment_status_id` = 1)
GROUP BY `person`.`id`
ORDER BY `person`.`last_name`
```

Comment: Same problem as Rolando, if the quiz hasn't been taken, there's not just a null field, here isn't a row to check against, since each score has its own row.

Comment: I don't know if you looked at this before the edit with the `CROSS JOIN`. The `CROSS JOIN` ensures that there is a row for each person with each module.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss that line, I'll see if I can work it in, have to go back and check the db and the tables the account has access to

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz `CROSS JOIN` has come in handy several times when I need a product table. If this answer worked for you, please accept it as such. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to work on the getting a table of modules created (why one doesn't already exist, I don't know...) Thanks for your help, and fear not, as soon as I have it working, I will except an answer!

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is use the [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function on the score

Then, use ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT

Here is my proposed query

```
SELECT
    person.id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(tilt.quiz.score,0) ORDER BY tilt.quiz.module) AS scores
FROM person
    LEFT JOIN enrollment ON person.id = enrollment.person_id
    LEFT JOIN tilt.quiz ON person.id = tilt.quiz.person_id 
WHERE 
    enrollment.course_id = '$num' AND enrollment_status_id = 1
GROUP BY person.id
ORDER BY last_name
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put the order by inside the concat, so thank you. However, if the student has not taken the quiz, there is no row for it, not just a null field. So if the student skipped quiz 3 for example, it needs to return 100,99,0,98,97,96,95,94, not 100,99,98,97,96,95,94